# Should I use "support of" or "support to" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

"Heavy construction will furnish direct support [to/of] the company's real estate operations." Would "to" or "of" be proper?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but how about this wording? _Heavy construction will directly support the company's real estate operations_.

Comment: J.R.'s wording is preferable, but if you must use a preposition here, *for* is better than both of the ones you suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Support of" vs. "Support for"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91106/support-of-vs-support-for)

Comment: Related quesiton, [“support to” vs. “support of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106148/support-to-vs-support-of).

Comment: Not a dupe since in this case both are wrong.

Comment: I don't see this as a dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91106/support-of-vs-support-for  That discusses "of and for" this is asking about "to and of" and in a slightly different context.   And in this case I believe the ***to*** is better here because support is being furnished *to* operations.

Answer (score -1):

I shouldn't use either. Use **for**.

Comment: It would be better if you could elaborate on why you think ***for*** should be used.

Answer (score -3):

"Towards" is what you're looking for.

"Heavy construction will furnish direct support **towards** the company's real estate operations."